# Как пошагово посмотреть в отладчике как работает функция?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, отладка, visual-studio-2015

Допустим у меня есть функция:

```
double Rec(double x, int n)
{
   if(n < 0)
   {
       x = 1.0 / x;
       n = -n;
   }
   if (n > 0)
   {
    return x*Rec(x, n - 1);
   }
   else
   return 1.0;
}

int main()
{
   double x = 2.0;
   for (int index = -3; index <= 3; ++index)
        cout << x << "in two == " << Rec(x, index) << endl;
}
```

Как посмотреть в отладчике как она работает пошагово?

Запускаю отладчик, он работает только в функции `main()` и не показывает что происходит в функции `Rec()`.

Comment: Убедитесь что вы собрали программу под Debug, и используйте шаги с заходом внутрь (Step Into). Также в процессе отладки в контекстном меню (по правой кнопке мыши) есть выбор в какую функцию зайти -- когда в строчке их несколько.

Comment: @nzeemin Спасибо, всё получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Из комментария пользователя [@nzeemin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/207882/nzeemin):*

Убедитесь что вы собрали программу под *Debug*, и используйте шаги с заходом внутрь (*Step Into*). Также в процессе отладки в контекстном меню (по правой кнопке мыши) есть выбор, в какую функцию зайти, когда в строчке их несколько.